# DotNetCoreCLI@2 pack command failing with .NET 8 upgrade

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, .net-8.0

I have just upgraded one of our projects to .NET 8 and the devops pipeline is now failing on the pack command.

A lot of the errors seem to look like this

> Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Xml.Serialization.dll' and 'Platform:System.Xml.Serialization.dll'. Could not determine winner due to equal file and assembly versions.

and

> 13:11>GenerateNuspec:
> NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: The file 'D:\agent\1_work\16\s\DotNet\CoreLibs\xxx\bin\Release\net8.0\xxx.dll' to be packed was not found on disk.
>
> at NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.PackTaskLogic.InitLibFiles(IMSBuildItem[] libFiles, IDictionary`2 aliases)   at NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.PackTaskLogic.GetPackArgs(IPackTaskRequest`1 request)
> at NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.PackTask.Execute()
> Done executing task "PackTask" -- FAILED.
> 13:11>Done building target "GenerateNuspec" in project "xxx.Core.csproj" -- FAILED.
> 13:11>Done Building Project "D:\agent\1_work\16\s\DotNet\CoreLibs\xxx\xxx.Core.csproj" (pack target(s)) -- FAILED.

I found this issue

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10335

I have tried setting all of my projects to have

```
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>False</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

and

```
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

But neither seems to help - however if i run the pack command locally using the  `-p:GeneratePackageOnBuild=false` flag, then the package builds successfully.

I am a bit lost on how to progress, any help would be appreciated.